# Correct MySQL syntax for deleting records where Column values are between a range specified

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all records in a MySQL table where the values in 'id' column is more than some value and less than some value..

I tried this :

```
 DELETE FROM `jos_users` WHERE `id` > 1303856 AND 'id' < 2557250 ;
```

But what happen is that all the records > 1303856 got deleted ..including the ids having value  2557250 and more than 2557250...

So what could be the correct mysql query or syntax in this situation?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `AND 'id' < 2557250` compares the string 'id' to the number 2557250. there is a difference between ` and '.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could try between

```
delete from `jos_users` where id between 1303856 and 2557250
```

> This should work as well. take note of the `id`  and 'id'. Diff between `` and ''

```
DELETE FROM `jos_users` WHERE `id` > 1303856 AND `id` < 2557250 ;
```

Comment: oh oops ...u r right i put ''..my mistake. So basically even my query could have worked if i used proper '' ?